# PACE JS - Apenas no Load da Página

Tags: javascript, plugin

Estou usando esse plugin, Page.JS - http://github.hubspot.com/pace/ - para fazer uma barra de progresso no site.

Estou chamando assim:

```
<script src='js/vendor/pace.min.js' data-pace-options='{ "elements": false, "startOnPageLoad": true, "restartOnRequestAfter": false }'></script>
```

Está funcionando parcialmente. Quando entro na página carrega a barra de progresso.

O problema é que isso está acontecendo em toda requisição. Como é uma Single Page meu site, tenho um script que ao rolar a tela vai trocando a URL. Por exemplo, tenho um MENU assim:

Home 
Contato
Produtos

E ao rolar para determinada sessão, vai fazendo `localhost/pagina#home`, `localhost/pagina#contato`e assim vai.

E quando rolo a página fica aparecendo a barra de progresso.

Não estou entendendo como funciona esse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por `default`, esse plugin adiciona a barra de progresso para todos os eventos do jQuery, se você precisa só no evento de carregamento da pagina, pode manter o `"startOnPageLoad": true` e adicionar o `"ajax": false` que evitara de ficar exibindo a cada requisição. Ficando assim:

```
<script src='js/vendor/pace.min.js' data-pace-options='{ "elements": false, "startOnPageLoad": true, "ajax": false, "restartOnRequestAfter": false }'></script>
```

Comment: Além disso, usei também o  `restartOnPushState: false` nessa linha. Obrigado.

Comment: opa.. sempre a disposição ;D

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar acrescentar o `ignoreURLs` nas options:

```
Pace.options = {
  ajax: {
    ignoreURLs: ['some-substring', /some-regexp/]
  }
}
```